# MySQL Query Return Indented Sub-Values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, csv

Misleading and confusing title, I know, but I couldn't figure out how to word what I needed done...

I currently have a MySQL query that returns the following sample results:
[FirstQuery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfyiJ.jpg)

```
|Invoice #|SO #|Customer|Invoice Date|Total|Sub-Invoice #|Part #|Line Item|Qty|
   34109    2    Fluke    2016-07-01  $988     34109        25    Cable     1
   34109    2    Fluke    2016-07-01  $988     34109        35    Relay     1
   34110    3    Fluke    2016-07-03  $215     34110        100   Cable     1
   34110    3    Fluke    2016-07-03  $215     34110        101   Relay     2
   34110    3    Fluke    2016-07-03  $215     34110        102   Remote    2
   34110    3    Fluke    2016-07-03  $215     34110        103   PCB Bd    1
```

But what I'd like the query to do is not repeat the first 6 columns for each row value where the Sub-Invoice number starts.  I'd like to see it return something like this:
[Preferred Query Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHYbk.jpg)

```
|Invoice #|SO #|Customer|Invoice Date|Total|Sub-Invoice #|Part #|Line Item|Qty|
   34109    2    Fluke    2016-07-01  $988     34109        25    Cable     1
                                                            35    Relay     1
   34110    3    Fluke    2016-07-03  $215     34110        100   Cable     1
                                                            101   Relay     2
                                                            102   Remote    2
                                                            103   PCB Bd    1
```

This way it doesn't repeat the same uneeded info over and over and just has the invoice line items broken down into their own rows.  Is this possible in MySQL?  I'm doing this all in PHPmyAdmin

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of posting images (Which some people can't see, for example, they are blocked on my current network) - could you make an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with an example of data?

Comment: Yes it is, add some sample data as text to your question or sqlfiddle

Comment: "I currently have a MySQL query that returns the following sample results" post de query..

Comment: looks you me you are going to need that query you already have use that as a subquery and pivot on the column invoice_number and use GROUP_CONCAT on line description. and Qty_ordered.

Comment: I can't figure out how to get sqlfiddle to work....

Comment: Then add sample data as text to your question.

Comment: I can't add sample data as text cleanly to this post, there's too many columns and it wraps and is totally unreadable

Comment: Simplfy it, the number of columns is not the issue.

Comment: Okay, I finally got it

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from docs;
+----+--------+--------+
| id | id_sub | id_obj |
+----+--------+--------+
|  1 |      1 |      1 |
|  2 |      1 |      2 |
|  3 |      1 |      3 |
|  4 |      1 |     10 |
|  5 |      1 |      1 |
|  6 |      1 |     10 |
|  7 |      1 |      3 |
|  8 |      1 |     10 |
|  9 |      1 |      1 |
| 10 |      2 |     30 |
| 11 |      2 |     10 |
| 12 |      2 |      1 |
| 13 |      2 |     10 |
| 14 |      4 |      1 |
| 15 |      5 |      1 |
| 16 |      6 |      1 |
| 17 |      7 |      1 |
| 18 |      7 |     10 |
| 19 |      7 |     11 |
+----+--------+--------+
19 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then you can detect a change in id_sub using a variable

```
select   if(id_sub <> @p, id_sub,'') id_sub,
         @p:=id_sub p
from docs cross join(select @p:='') p
order by id
```

result

```
 +--------+---+
| id_sub | p |
+--------+---+
| 1      | 1 |
|        | 1 |
|        | 1 |
|        | 1 |
|        | 1 |
|        | 1 |
|        | 1 |
|        | 1 |
|        | 1 |
| 2      | 2 |
|        | 2 |
|        | 2 |
|        | 2 |
| 4      | 4 |
| 5      | 5 |
| 6      | 6 |
| 7      | 7 |
|        | 7 |
|        | 7 |
+--------+---+
19 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Is it possible to SELECT more than just that 1 field while also having the IF statement run?

Comment: Read up concat.